# CSS: Display all images with the same height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a gallery and I want to display all images with the same height no matter what size they have like this picture:
[image]
I set at the title **Using CSS** but t be honest I'm not sure if this is possible using `CSS` or `Javascript`, so I hope someone can put me in the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img { height: 200px; width: auto; }
```

Comment: Lol it's that simple. Thanks :)

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer :)

Comment: @paper1111 no they are actually well displayed.